# How to create the Surface for the SurfaceHolder?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to get an application to paint something on a canvas every half a second, but the `SurfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()` returns false, and when I call `SurfaceHolder.lockCanvas()` this returns `null`.

As per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577256/how-to-get-a-surfaceholder-with-a-valid-surface-needed-by-egl-eglcreatewindowsu), I should use a `SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceCreated` but the surface is never created.

The `onCreate` method from my main `Activity`

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    ChartPainter p = new ChartPainter(this);

    }
```

And part of my `ChartPainter.java`

```
public ChartPainter(Context context) {
    super(context);
    holder = getHolder();
    final boolean a[] = new boolean[1];
    a[0] = false;
    holder.addCallback(new Callback() {



        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        a[0] = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
            int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

});

} [...]//more omitted code here
```

How do I create the surface for the `SurfaceHolder`?

Answer (score 1):

Does ChartPainter extends SurfaceView?

Note: SurfaceHolder is usually used with SurfaceView. When the activity goes to the foreground and its SurfaceView is about to be rendered, WindowManager will ask SurfaceFlinger to create a new surface. Then SurfaceHolder's surfaceCreated() will be called.

Comment: Not really an answer

Comment: I need to dig up the code and I will get back to you, thanks for your suggestion.